# “No data available in table” from firebase

Tags: html, firebase, datatable

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    var dataSet = [
    ['']
];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Full Name" },
            { title: "Email" },
            { title: "Access Group" },
            { title: "Status." },
            { title: "Date Deactivated" },
            { title: "Action" }
        ]
      } );
    });
  </script>
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="UsersList"> 
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

it shows in jquery dataTable but there is alertbox says!

DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

'<' it's used as a tag or code starting.Use '>' instead and exhange the values.

Comment: This does not address OPs question properly. It's unclear what you're suggesting. Please provide more details